# unable to find valid certification path after reinstalling JDK

Tags: jetty, java, keystore

Running jetty server with ant script that starts it.

I keep getting this exception after JDK reinstall:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX
path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target.
```

1. Reinstalled JAVA jdk1.6.0_26.
2. set JAVA home to ...\Java\jdk1.6.0_26.
3. Inserted certificate into keystore at ..\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre\lib\security

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recompile all your classes with JDK 1.6.